# How to add styles to Django model field's help_text in the generic views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a Django model where in I want to display help text as shown below:

```
class StaffRoles(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8, verbose_name="Role", help_text='Field accepts all uppercase only')
    role_short_text = models.CharField(max_length=35, verbose_name='Short Desc')
    role_long_text = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Description')
```

Now when I use the model in Django generic `CreateView` to add a new **Role**, the help text is displayed in the page in a default style just next to the input field `role`.

What I am trying to do is to add some style to the help text being displayed, and to that end I tried to modify my template code as shown below:

The **template** code:

```
...
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if field.name == "role" %}
        {{ field }}
        <small style="color:teal">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

However, to my dismay the help text is displayed twice - i.e. the resultant **help** text as a result of the new code line added, plus the text that was originally displayed.

**Is there a way I may display the help text with some css styles added?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class StaffRoles(models.Model):
    role = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8, verbose_name="Role", 
        help_text = mark_safe(_(
            '<small style="color:teal">Field accepts all uppercase only</small>'
        ))
    )

[..]
```

or you may override the default style of django admin contrib module.

## Update

As second option you need to override `change_form.html` to add you custom css file.

- under `templates` create folders like `/admin/YOUR-APP/change_form.html`
- add this code

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
/* your custom style */
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

have a look at base template for admin contrib package under `venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin` (i'm on windows using `venv`)

and refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates for more details ..

also you can completely override the look and feel of admin interface, there's already themes ready for use on `pypi`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you give me some pointer as to how may I get the same effect by **overriding default style in admin contrib module** in the generic class views?